# Assigning each answer with different points in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I embedded Google Forms to my blog and I want to assign different points to each answer in the multiple choice.

> A = 1 point, B = 2 points, C = 3 points, D = 4 points.

There is no such feature in Google Forms. Are there any add-ons that will help me do this or how would I use app scripts to assign each answer worths different points?

Comment: New Google Forms has a new feature.  Click the settings gear/cog wheel, and then click the Quizzes tab, and turn on quizzes.  Then you can assign points to questions.

Comment: @SandyGood Within the question, i also want to assign different points to the answers.

Comment: Have you found an easy way to do this? I'm looking for the same feature. Is there an add-on you found/made for that purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it will be any help
What I've done is a duplicate of the spreadsheet containing the answers, keeping only the headers
Below each questions, i listed the possible answers, a delimiter and the values
basically something like that
Is this answer useful?
Yes|10
Perhaps|5
No|0
I scripted a loop used to look for each question, then I looped down in the column, splitting ech value to look for the possible answer, and cumulating the points as a total score. Actually, I also added a group score.

BR

Comment: can you share some code ? the whole thing actually?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Question type to Multiple choice grid

- Add the Questions in Rows
- If you changed from Multiple choice, remove the Columns
- Click Answer Key
  Now you can assign points to each option

[image]

Comment: This works great! However, I'm not seeing an option to both (1) limit responses to 1 per column (so that users don't get extra points by answering all of the options) and (2) make the question itself required. Do you know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

to change the question type as in the picture you need Scorecery -a paid service

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32290905)